# Ruby: how to overload arithmetic operations between numeric types and user-defined types

Tags: ruby

In Ruby the expression `1 + Complex(1,1)` yields a `Complex`.

I would like to achieve the same for a user-defined type, so that `(1 + MyType.new(...))` yields a value of `MyType`

Similarly for `(1 - MyType.new(...))`, but subtraction is not commutative.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use coercion to handle this like so:

```
class MyType
  attr_reader :value
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end 
  def +(n)
    if n.is_a?(MyType)
      MyType.new(self.value + n.value)
    else
      @value += n 
      self
    end 
  end 
  def coerce(other)
    [MyType.new(other), self]
  end
end

1 + MyType.new(12) 
#=> #<MyType:0x0000561609d5d9a8 @r=13>
# or even 
1 + MyType.new(12) + 3 
#=> #<MyType:0x0000561bc671d170 @r=16>
```

When the `Integer` 1 receives `MyType` as an argument to the `+` method it does not know how to handle it directly so it will try and coerce it to something it can understand by calling `coerce` on the argument object and passing itself to the `coerce` method.

The `coerce` method should always return an `Array` containing 2 values. `Integer` will then try and `+` those together using the first as the receiver and the second as the argument.

So essentially something like this:

```
a = 1
b = MyType.new(12) 
begin 
  a + b
rescue TypeError 
  b.coerce(a).reduce(&:+)
end
```

[This article](https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/class-coercion-in-ruby/) offers a far more in-depth explanation of how the coercion works along with examples of when this would be useful.

Comment: Very interesting. Another example: `1.2 + MyType.new(12) + Rational(3,4)
 #=> #<MyType:0x00005abcba32b230 @value=13.95>`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland ahhh a coercion chain very nice

Comment: Works great for commutative operators like '+'. What about non-commutative operators? 3 - x != x - 3

Comment: @engineersmnky -- Thanks!